# Armadillo library difference between square brackets [] and parenthesis ()

Tags: c++, armadillo

Armadillo library provides 3 ways for [element access](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_access):

1. via `()`;
2. via `[]`;
3. via `at()`;

I noticed that there is difference in perfomance when using each of them. I tested the code below:

```
size_t n_row = 500, n_col = 500;

{ // ()
    wall_clock timer;
    mat matrix(n_row, n_col, fill::zeros);
    timer.tic();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_row; i++){
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n_col; j++){
            matrix(i, j) = i+j;
        }
    }
    std::cout << timer.toc() << std::endl;
}

{ // []
    wall_clock timer;
    mat matrix(n_row, n_col, fill::zeros);
    timer.tic();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_row; i++){
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n_col; j++){
            matrix[i, j] = i+j;
        }
    }
    std::cout << timer.toc() << std::endl;
}

{ // .at()
    wall_clock timer;
    mat matrix(n_row, n_col, fill::zeros);
    timer.tic();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_row; i++){
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n_col; j++){
            matrix.at(i, j) = i+j;
        }
    }
    std::cout << timer.toc() << std::endl;
}
```

The result is:

1. via `()` 0.0008 sec;
2. via `[]` 0.0003 sec;
3. via `at()` 0.0007 sec;

Is anybody able to comment the given result?
I use Windows 10 x64, MSVC 2017, Release mode, Qt 5.14.2
I set `#define ARMA_NO_DEBUG` in `config.hpp`

Comment: Armadillo [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_access) states that `#define ARMA_NO_DEBUG` is **not** a good idea until all bugs in your code have been detected and removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is mostly in the link you gave:

- "`.at(n)` or  `[n]` As for (n), but without a bounds check. Not recommended for use unless your code has been thoroughly debugged."

  - So the first part of the answer is that `.at(n)` and `[n]` are potentially slightly faster, but less safe, than `(n)`, which is maybe why `()` access took longest in your tests.
  - But `[n]` and `.at(n)` are the same, and the difference in times you saw is just same artefact of the way you ran or timed the tests. This is not a surprise because benchmarking is notoriously difficult, it is not just a matter of running something in a loop with some timing as you're doing. (Actually this is probably even the real reason for the time difference you saw with `()`.)
  - This convention is confusingly different from STL containers: normally `[]` is unchecked and `.at()` is checked, while `()` for indexing doesn't exist at all.
- There are also `(i,j)` and `.at(i,j)` and also `(i,j,k)` and `.at(i,j,k)`, but no `[i,j]` or `[i,j,k]`.

  - So the reason for the seemingly redudant existence of both `.at()` and `[]` is that `[]` is not available for more than one index (but is presumably still available for the one-index case because it's so much more natural than `.at()`).
  - This is not mentioned in the link, but that's because C++ does not allow overloading the `operator[]` function with multiple parameters, so this would always end up being interpreted as `[(i,j)]` which ends up being evaluated as `[i]` - the `j` is evaluated (e.g. if it is a function call) but then silently thrown away!

In reality, checked index access is highly unlikely to be a bottleneck in most applications, and in many cases might be totally optimised away by the compiler anyway (at least in release mode). So my suggestion is to just always use round bracket `mat(ind)` notation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I set `#define ARMA_NO_DEBUG` in config file. That should turn off all the boudary checks. Also I can use `[i,j]` indexing and it works

Comment: In that case, the whole difference in timing you're seeing is due to random fluctuations. Try replacing the three different indexing method with exactly the same indexing method copy and pasted three times and you will surely see the same fluctuations.

Comment: As for `[i,j]` indexing, I guarantee this will not work, it is not possible in C++. As extra evidence, it is clearly not supported in Armadillo docs and the whole reason `.at()` exists is to allow checked indexing with multiple parameters. It will *compile* but give incorrect results: effectively the `j` is completely ignored for the reason I said in the answer and because Armadillo does linear indexing when you supply one index for a 2d matrix. [Edit: or maybe it's `i` that's ignored, but the point is the same.]

Comment: Yes, `[i,j]` indexing gives me wrong result. Thank you!